# How to get the POST request data in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, digital-ocean, serverless

I have the following serverless function with DigitalOcean (similar to Lambda):

```
function process(params) {
    //access URL parameters like params.t, params.var, etc
}

exports.main = process;
```

The issue with this is that I only know how to pass data as a `GET` request, how can I do it as a `POST`?

How do I retrieve `POST` data?

If I send a `POST` request, I get the following error:

```
Response is not valid 'message/http
```

Since the `process()` function doesn't know how to deal with the POST data.

This is how DigitalOcean says to do it:

```
function main(args) { 
   switch (args.__ow_method) {
      case 'GET': ...
      case 'POST': ...
   }
}
```

But that does not even work for both `GET` and `POST` as `args` only contains the URL parameters (`._ow_method` doesn't even exist).

How can I get the `POST` data in Node, not just the GET

**Update** - Just did a workaround by making a POST request via `cURL` - the `params` parameter just picks up the values

Comment: @Phil `totally different code`, I just set up a Lambda environment and it works very similarly - in this context it is identical, including the `exports.main = process;`. Do you get free Reputation from removing tags?

Comment: There's a big difference between AWS's [handler implementation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html) which accepts `event` and `context` parameters and Digital Ocean's which accepts a [single `args` parameter](https://github.com/digitalocean/sample-functions-nodejs-helloworld/blob/master/packages/sample/hello/hello.js#L1). If you want AWS answers that won't apply to your project, by all means keep using AWS tags

Comment: _"`._ow_method` doesn't even exist"_... you can see the structure of `args` [here in this Typescript sample](https://github.com/digitalocean/sample-functions-apollo-graphql/blob/main/packages/default/graphql/ApolloServer.ts#L23). The property is `__ow_method` (double-underscore prefix). The values [appear to be lowercase](https://github.com/digitalocean/sample-functions-apollo-graphql/blob/main/packages/default/graphql/ApolloServer.ts#L83) so try comparing to `"post"` instead

Comment: If that's still not working, could you please [edit] your question to show how you're making the request? See also the `curl` examples in [the docs](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/functions/how-to/develop-functions/#invoke-a-function-with-parameters)

Comment: @Phil Sorry for coming off harsh, thanks for the link I'll see if I can solve it based on that then will update this question with the solution

Comment: No worries (and no, I don't get rep points for editing tags ). The DigitalOcean docs are woefully inadequate so I completely understand your frustration

Comment: @Phil `DigitalOcean docs are woefully inadequate` true haha. And I was able to get it to work by just doing everything through `cURL` rather than normal GET requests in the browser

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same `Response is not valid 'message/http'` error with DO functions, although on python runtime. Sharing in case it helps others.

My function worked when triggered from the dashboard, but not via browser or curl. The lack of debugging tools or logs didn't help, nor did the inconsistent behaviour between dashboard and curl/browser.

My mistake was not returning a dict with the components [required by DO](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/functions/reference/parameters-responses/) (see Returns section), which should be:

```
{
    "body": <required>,       # This is where your response goes! 
                              # Can be dict (for JSON response) or text
    "statusCode": <optional>, # Http status code, default=200
    "headers": <optional>     # Dict of additional headers
}
```

Whereas I'd just put my return value at the top level of the dict, not under `body`.